# Running a Shell script inside a Perl script

Tags: perl, shell

I have a Perl script containing file name which contains periods:

```
$zipfile = FS.one.two.$file_date_str.three.1_1.zip;
```

where `$file_date_str` contains date in `YYYYMMDD` format.

I want to read this file locally and then `ftp` it to a remote location. The file name at the remote location is different in the sense that it has to be prefixed with `CD.ABCD123.`

I wrote below lines to do this:

```
$filePrefix=CD.ABCD123.;
$scpcmd = '$myscriptdir/ftpscript $zipfile $filePrefix${zipfile} ${REMOTE_ID}@${REMOTE_SERVER}';
print L $scpcmd . "\n";
$ret=system($scpcmd);
```

`ftpscript` is a unix shell script which ftps the file to remote location.

I get below error on running this:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at my_script_name line 77, near "1_1.zip"
    (Missing operator before zip?)
Bareword found where operator expected at my_script_name line 92, near "1_1.zip"
    (Missing operator before zip?)
syntax error at my_script_name line 77, near "1_1.zip"
syntax error at my_script_name line 92, near "1_1.zip"
```

I am new to Perl scripting. Could someone please help with what am I doing wrong above?

Comment: Note that `$myscriptdir` etc. won't be expanded within single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow sneak's advice about setting `zipfile`, but you also need some more changes

Change:

```
$scpcmd = '$myscriptdir/ftpscript $zipfile $filePrefix${zipfile} ${REMOTE_ID}@${REMOTE_SERVER}';
```

Into:

```
$scpcmd = "$myscriptdir/ftpscript $zipfile $filePrefix${zipfile} ${REMOTE_ID}\@${REMOTE_SERVER}";
```

---

BTW, be sure to notice the `\@` inside the double quoted string. This is to prevent perl from looking for an array. (e.g.) `"hello @world"` will try to embed an array named `world`, just as it would a scalar named `world` for `"hello $world"`

Comment: Thanks. The syntax for appending filePrefix, does that look correct ?

Comment: Yes. I believe they are your only two problems. I can't tell from the post which is correct/desired, but do you need a "/" between filePrefix and zipfile or not? I looked over everything you posted and could find no other issues [and I've been doing perl for 20+]. I might have missed something, but, otherwise things are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples (which appear edited, making it a bit harder to troubleshoot), it appears as if you have failed to quote the strings.

Instead of

```
$zipfile = FS.one.two.$file_date_str.three.1_1.zip;
```

try

```
$zipfile = "FS.one.two." . $file_date_str . ".three.1_1.zip";
```

Comment: And what about $filePrefix and $scpcmd. Does those lines look ok to you perl syntax wise ?